# Question about an example of Quotient space.

Tags: general-topology

I am new to the concept of Quotient space, and I have an example of a Quotient space from one of my lecture notes, which I can't understand.

Here is the example quoted from the lecture note:

> A circle $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=1\}$ can be thought of as the interval $[0,2\pi]$ **with end points identified** $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{R}/\sim$ where $x\sim x' \iff x-x'\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{R}/\sim'$ where $x\sim' x'\iff x-x'\in2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Since $S^1\in\mathbb{R^2}$, it has a subspace topology. We want $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ to get its topology **from $[0,2\pi]$** and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to get its topology **from $\mathbb{R}$**. And **it should be same topology.**

(This lecture note was written by a professor, not by me. And the quote above is exactly quoted from the lecture note.)

My question is:

1. what does it mean by "...with end points identified..."?
2. Why do we want $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ to get its topology from $[0,2\pi]$? I mean, shouldn't we want $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ to get its topology from $P([0,2\pi]/\sim)$, the power set of $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ ? (The same question holds for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.)
3. What does it mean by "... it should be same topology..."? Does it mean that the topology on $[0,2\pi]/\sim$ should be the same topology on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$? If so, why? And what about the topology on $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: How did you define the quotient space? There are several ways to do this and the answer depends on that.

Comment: Actually, the professor who wrote this lecture note didn't defined the Quotient space before the above example. He just wrote the title "Quotient topology" and then started writing this example. So, I don't understand how to understand this example. (But he defined the Product space and open function between two topological spaces.)

Comment: end points identified i.e $x\sim y$ iff $x=0$ and $y=2\pi$ or $x=2\pi$ and $y=0$ or $x=y$(the unique two point identified are $0$ and $2\pi$) intuitively we obtain the circle  from $[0,2\pi]$ by  gluing the two points $0$ and $2\pi$   . and there are some topological properties hereditary form $[0,2\pi]$ (for example the compactness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at first $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$. This is obtained from $\Bbb R$ by taking the quotient w.r.t. the equivalance relation $\sim'$. 
   In other words, every $x\in\Bbb R$ is '*identified with*' $x+2\pi k$ for every $k\in\Bbb Z$ *in the quotient space*. 
   Now, each real number is represented in $[0,2\pi]$, moreover, each is represented exactly once, except for the endpoints $0$ and $2\pi$, who are identified to each other in $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$. 
   To make it visible, we just *glue* the two endpoints of a thread (of original form straight segment).
2. So, when we identify (glue) some points to one another in an original space, we arrive to a quotient space, and it has a natural topology inherited from the original space: namely, let a subset $U\subseteq\, X/\sim\ $  *open* whenever its preimage $\{x\in X\,:\,[x]_\sim\in U\}$ is open. 
   Well, you are right in a sense, as the topology is defined in terms of *subsets*.
3. It means that the same subsets are open w.r.t. these topologies. 
   More precisely, what we have is *homeomorphisms* (i.e. one-to-one continuous and open preserving mappings) between $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, $\ \Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$, $\ [0,2\pi]/\sim'$ and the circle $S^1$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. 
   The thing here is that in either case the open subsets are exactly the (arbitrary) unions of open intervals (e.g., this is what you get when you intersect $S^1$ with an open disk on $\Bbb R^2$).

Comment: For the first question, I understand $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ was used to identify two end points $0$ and $2\pi$ if I understood correctly. Then, do you have any idea why the professor mentioned $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ in the context of identifying two end points?

Comment: It is easier to work with $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and by scaling ($x\mapsto 2\pi x$ with inverse $x\mapsto x/2\pi$, both continuous) we can obtain a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$, meaning that these spaces *are the same* (at least topologically).

Comment: @Yk26 He mean $[0,2\pi]$ and not $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$! . Look carefully this phrase: **can be thought of as the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with end points identified**

Comment: @Hamou Yes I know. What I am asking is that why $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is mentioned **after** the sentence **"... can be thought of as the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with end points identified..."** parallel with $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. (i.e. there is no period after the sentence "... can be thought of as the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with end points identified")

Comment: via $ t\mapsto e^{2i\pi t}$, we have $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\simeq S^{1}$.